# How to convert a LINQ query to use lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to switch this linq code to a lambda expression:

```
foreach (var id in orderLinesToSplit)
{
    int result =
        (from ol in orderLines
        from splittedOl in orderLines
        where ol.Key == id
            && ol.Value == splittedOl.Value
            && ol.Key != splittedOl.Key
        select splittedOl.Key).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The goal is to get a `Dictionary<int, int>` of pairs `id` (from `oderLinesToSplit`) and `result` (the result from the linq query). Can it be done with just one lambda expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result= 
(
    from ol in orderLines
    from splittedOl in orderLines
    where orderLinesToSplit.Contains(ol.Key)
        && ol.Value == splittedOl.Value
        && ol.Key != splittedOl.Key
      select new
      {
        splittedOl.Key,
        splittedOl.Value
      }
    ).ToDictionary (v =>v.Key,v=>v.Value);
```

Or if you really want it in one expression. Then something like this:

```
var result=
    (
        db.orderLines.Join
            (
                db.splittedOl,
                ol=>ol.Value,
                splittedOl=>splittedOl.Value,
                (ol,splittedOl)=>new 
                {
                    olKey=ol.Key,
                    splittedOlKey=splittedOl.Key
                }
            ).Where(l =>l.olKey!= l.splittedOlKey && orderLinesToSplit.Contains(l.olKey))
            .ToDictionary(l =>l.olKey,v=>v.splittedOlKey)
    );
```

Where db is the linq data context

Comment: @LauraJimenez Why do you need it as a lambda expression? Its the same query, just harder to read.

Comment: @Magnus agree. It's more easy to read. Does the same thing. I don't get the point ether.